# HttpClient request crashes on a Xamarin Notification Service Extensions iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-extensions

I'm trying to request some data from an API using `HttpClient` in `DidReceiveNotificationRequest` method (Xamarin iOS Notification Service Extensions project).

When the `GetAsync` (`HttpClient`) the extension just crashes.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
public override async void DidReceiveNotificationRequest(UNNotificationRequest request, Action<UNNotificationContent> contentHandler)
{
    ...

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        await client.GetAsync("https://google.com").ConfigureAwait(false); // crashes here
    }

    ...
}
```

I also tried to use a `NSUrlSessionHandler` as the `HttpClient` handler, but no success.

Comment: have you tried catching and logging the exception?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but no exception was thrown

Answer (score 0):

try use with Uri:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(client.BaseAddress + resource, string.Empty));
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

and for iOS need add to .plist - NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription

maybe need add HttpMessageHandler:

```
 client = new HttpClient(CreateClientHandler()) { BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://{Address}:5001") };
....

private HttpClientHandler CreateClientHandler()
    {
       return new HttpClientHandler
       {
           ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }
       };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Denys, I tried your code but no success. I've noticed that if I avoid the async/await and use .Result the code worked. It seems something related to async code.